# Compress sitemap.xml into sitemap.xml.gz in php making the file damage

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to convert the sitemap.xml into sitemap.xml.gz , The pages I am extracting from the database , it is converting into sitemap.xml , but when I am trying to compress this is not working . this is my code it is making the file damage .

```
  header('content-type: application/x-gzip');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="sitemap.xml.gz"');

        $xmlString = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
$xmlString .= '<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">';

   include("admin/functions/dbconfig.php");


$sql = "select * from zz where aa between 1 and 30000";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql); 
while ($row =  mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$url = $row["aa"];
$xmlString .= '<url>';
$xmlString .= '<loc>http://mynewdomain.com/page.php?word='.htmlentities($url).'</loc>';
$xmlString .= '<lastmod>'.date("Y-m-d").'</lastmod>';
$xmlString .= '<changefreq>monthly</changefreq>';
$xmlString .= '<priority>0.5</priority>';
$xmlString .= '</url>';
}

$xmlString .= '</urlset>';
gzwrite("compress", gzencode($xmlString));
gzclose("compress");
```

Comment: I think you're missing a call to [`gzopen`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzwrite.php) somewhere. Where you're using the string `"compress", you're supposed to have a resource argument.

Comment: @iainn letme add and test

Comment: @iainn still showing damage